# Terraform complex type value doesn't work

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

```
variable "evstream_cluster" {

  type = map(object({
    name = string
    kafka_version = string
    broker = map(object({
      node_count = number
      node_instance_type = string
      ebs_volume_size_gb = number
    }))
  }))

  default = {
    name = "evstream",
    kafka_version = "2.2.1",
    broker = {
      node_count = 3,
      node_instance_type = "m5.large",
      ebs_volume_size_gb =  500
    }
  }
}
```

This code fails with the following error, I tried changing the object syntax to a map syntax and it fails too.

```
> terraform -version
Terraform v0.12.25

> terraform validate
Error: Invalid default value for variable

  on variables.tf line 39, in variable "evstream_cluster":
  39:   default = {
  40:     name = "evstream"
  41:     kafka_version = "2.2.1"
  42:     broker = {
  43:       node_count = 3
  44:       node_instance_type = "m5.large"
  45:       ebs_volume_size_gb =  500
  46:     }
  47:   }

This default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint:
element "name": object required.
```

Appreciate any help providing a value that works, which would help understand terraform type system.

Answer (score 3):

Is it a map of objects you're after or just single object? If it's the latter this will work:

```hcl
variable "evstream_cluster" {

  type = object({
    name = string
    kafka_version = string
    broker = object({
      node_count = number
      node_instance_type = string
      ebs_volume_size_gb = number
    })
  })

  default = {
    name = "evstream",
    kafka_version = "2.2.1",
    broker = {
      node_count = 3,
      node_instance_type = "m5.large",
      ebs_volume_size_gb =  500
    }
  }
}
```